# Verilog concatenation of decimal and string literal

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to concatenate decimal with the string. Like:

```
parameter AWIDTH = 15;
...
...

wire [AWIDTH-1:0] addra_bus;
assign addra_bus = cg_one ? {addra} : {AWIDTH, "'bz"};
```

On basic of 'cg_one', it would pick either {addra} or {AWIDTH, "'bz"}. In false condition of ternary operator I am concatenating AWIDTH with 'bz. If cg_one is 1'b0, I should get 15'bz as value in addra_bus. Make sense?

Problem is while synthesizing this code. I get a warning as :

```
WARNING: expression size 56 truncated to fit in target size 15 (VERI-1209)
```

Why is it so? From where size 56 is coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using a string literal. All you need to do is

```
assign addra_bus = cg_one ? addra : 'z;
```

`'z` will be expanded to the width of addra_bus

Comment: At first sight, I thought this is magical stuff. :) But unfortunately, it did not work out. Geeting an erroe message this time : `ERROR: syntax error near ' (VERI-1137)`

Comment: That is legal SystemVerilog(See section 5.7.1 Integer literal constants of the 1800-2012 LRM), but perhaps your synthesis tool does not support it. You can also try `{AWIDTH{1'bz}}`, which is what I think you were attempting to do in the first place.

Comment: Ohh. I think I should have mentioned specifically about verilog here. And yes, there could be an possibility of my tool not supporting it. Anyway, your second suggestion of `{AWIDTH{1'bz}}` worked. I hope it return me `15bz`. Thanks for writing.

Comment: Then you should not have used the SystemVerilog tag. But most synthesis tools now accept this if you use .sv file extensions. Please accept this answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to save by default 32 bit `AWIDTH` and 24 bit `"'bz"` (56 bits in total) into 15 bit `addra_bus`.

You should limit the width of the `AWIDTH` and increase the width of `addra_bus` . For example:

```
parameter AWIDTH = 6'd30;

wire [AWIDTH-1:0] addra_bus;
assign addra_bus = cg_one ? {addra} : {AWIDTH, "'bz"};
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. I appreciate. What if I do not want to write AWIDTH in binary. It is decimal value for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave already mentioned to put the bus to high state you could do 
`assign addra_bus = cg_one ? addra : {AWIDTH{1'bz}};` But setting a bus to "z" in a synthesizable   code is not desired until you are driving a chip-level IO signal.

If you want to display the string 15'bz in the bus for debug .

```
reg [7:0]  val = {"0"+AWIDTH%10};
reg [7:0]  val1 = {("0"+AWIDTH/10)};
assign addra_bus = cg_one ? {addra} : {val,val1};
```

[ assuming you param size is only unto 99.][ as you need 8 bits per character the code above only displays "15" ]